# Template specialization with array as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize this function template:

```
template< typename T, std::size_t Size>
T Max(T(&pArr)[Size]) {
    T result{ *pArr };

    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < Size; i++) {
        result = pArr[i - 1] > pArr[i] ? pArr[i - 1] : pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I would like to specialize it for const char*. I have try many things but any of them work. When trying this way:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
const char* Max<const char*>(const char *(&pArr)[SIZE]) {
    char result{ *pArr };

    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < SIZE; i++) {
        result = pArr[i - 1] > pArr[i] ? pArr[i - 1] : pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting the error: 'Max': illegal use of explicit template arguments.
Could anyone help me with that? I would like to understand why it is not working and how to make it work.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't partial specialize a function.

Comment: you mean it should look like this?
template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
const char* Max<const char*, std::size_t>(const char *(&pArr)[SIZE])

Comment: Uhmmm... no; if nobody else do it before, I'll try to write an answer to explain better.

Comment: thank you! If I manage t make it work before your answer I will write here how I did it.

Comment: Unrelated to the error, your `Max` does not return the maximum element of an array, is it intended?

Comment: In addition, how can you initialize a `char` with `*pArr`, which is of type `const char*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that C++11 doesn't support partial specialization of template functions; only full specializations.

Given your `Max()` function, a possible full specialization is the following

```
template <>
int Max<int, 4u>(int(&pArr)[4u])
 {
   int result{ *pArr };

   for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < 4u; i++) 
      result = pArr[i - 1] > pArr[i] ? pArr[i - 1] : pArr[i];

   return result;
 }
```

You can go around this limitations inserting a function in a template struct/class and partial specialize the struct/class.

By example, given the following template `struct`, with a `static` `func()` function inside it

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct MaxS
 {
   static T func (T (&a)[N])
    {
      T result{ a[0] };

      for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < N; i++)
         result = a[i - 1] > a[i] ? a[i - 1] : a[i];

      return result;
    }
 };
```

you can partial specialize, say for all `int` C-style arrays, as follows

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct MaxS<int, N>
 {
   static int func (int (&a)[N])
    {
      int result{ a[0] };

      for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < N; i++)
         result = a[i - 1] > a[i] ? a[i - 1] : a[i];

      return result;
    }
 };
```

This way, unfortunately, you can't deduce the types and the sizes; so you have explicit they calling `func()`s (by example) as follows

```
MaxS<int, 4>::func(a)
```

The following is a full compiling example for both solutions

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T, std::size_t Size>
T Max(T(&pArr)[Size])
 {
   std::cout << "Max(), generic version" << std::endl;

   T result{ *pArr };

   for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < Size; i++)
      result = pArr[i - 1] > pArr[i] ? pArr[i - 1] : pArr[i];

   return result;
 }

template <>
int Max<int, 4u>(int(&pArr)[4u])
 {
   std::cout << "Max(), full specialization" << std::endl;

   int result{ *pArr };

   for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < 4u; i++) 
      result = pArr[i - 1] > pArr[i] ? pArr[i - 1] : pArr[i];

   return result;
 }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct MaxS
 {
   static T func (T (&a)[N])
    {
      std::cout << "MaxS::func(), generic version" << std::endl;

      T result{ a[0] };

      for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < N; i++)
         result = a[i - 1] > a[i] ? a[i - 1] : a[i];

      return result;
    }
 };

template <std::size_t N>
struct MaxS<int, N>
 {
   static int func (int (&a)[N])
    {
      std::cout << "MaxS::func(), int partial specialization" << std::endl;

      int result{ a[0] };

      for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < N; i++)
         result = a[i - 1] > a[i] ? a[i - 1] : a[i];

      return result;
    }
 };


int main()
{
   int  a [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   long b [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   int  c [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

   std::cout << Max(a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << Max(b) << std::endl;
   std::cout << Max(c) << std::endl;

   std::cout << MaxS<int, 4>::func(a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << MaxS<long, 4>::func(b) << std::endl;
   std::cout << MaxS<int, 5>::func(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot partial specialize a function. But you don't have to do that as functions already support overloading. You just have to create an overload for `const char*`. Your version has two bugs.

1. You have declared the result variable as `char` but it should be `const char*`.
2. Comparing random pointers using `>`, does not give a meaningful result. You have to decide how you call one bigger than the other.

Link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VKE4Jy

---

```
#include<cstring>

template< typename T, std::size_t Size>
T Max(T(&pArr)[Size]) {
    T result{ *pArr };

    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < Size; i++) {
        result = pArr[i - 1] > pArr[i] ? pArr[i - 1] : pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}

bool greater(const char* first, const char* second){
    return strlen(first) > strlen(second);
}

template<std::size_t SIZE>
const char* Max(const char *(&pArr)[SIZE]) {
    const char* result{ *pArr };

    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < SIZE; i++) {
        result = greater(pArr[i - 1],pArr[i]) ? pArr[i - 1] : pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int foo() {
    int ints[] = {1, 2};
    return Max(ints);
}

const char* bar() {
    const char* stuff[] = {"1222", "234", "sfsdfsd"};
    return Max(stuff);
}
```

---

- One more issue: `Max` assumes the array has at-least two elements. You can add a `static_assert` or handle the case correctly.
- FYI, there is a std lib algo `std::max_element` which can be used with arrays too. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element